# Sort table partly based on head-to-head results

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, sorting

I want to make a league table. Basically I have matches, that result in points and scores and I can sort them. But what I'm struggling with is the head-to-head aspect. See for instance the ranking below: "Sjachtar Donetsk" is above "Real Madrid" because their head to head result is better.

[image: League Table - head to head]

So I need a basic sort that orders points, but then I need some form of comparison. Besides the example with two team going head-to-head you also have the possibility of three teams with equal points.

Example in code (Games):

```
import pandas
import numpy
df_games = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.array(
[
    ["Club Brugge", "Galatasaray", 1, 1, 0], 
    ["Paris", "Real", 1, 1, 0],
    ["Real", "Club Brugge", 3, 0, 1],
    ["Galatasaray", "Paris", 3, 0, 1],
    ["Galatasaray", "Real", 3, 0, 1],
    ["Club Brugge", "Paris", 1, 1, 0],
    ["Real", "Galatasaray", 1, 1, 0],
    ["Paris", "Club Brugge", 1, 1, 0],
    ["Galatasaray", "Club Brugge", 1, 1, 0],
    ["Real", "Paris", 1, 1, 0]
]), columns=["home_team_id", "away_team_id", "result", "goals_home_team", "goals_away_team"])
df_games["result"] = pandas.to_numeric(df_games["result"], downcast="integer")
df_games["goals_away_team"] = pandas.to_numeric(df_games["goals_home_team"], downcast="integer")
df_games["goals_home_team"] = pandas.to_numeric(df_games["goals_away_team"], downcast="integer")
```

Clubs:

```
l_clubs = [
"Real",
"Paris",
"Club Brugge",
"Galatasaray"
]
```

Table

```
d_table = {}

for s_club in l_clubs:
    d_table[s_club] = {"i_games_played": 0, "i_wins": 0, "i_draws": 0, "i_losses": 0, "i_goals_scored": 0, "i_goals_conceded": 0, "i_points": 0}
for index, row in df_games.iterrows():
# add game played
d_table[row["home_team_id"]]["i_games_played"] += 1
d_table[row["away_team_id"]]["i_games_played"] += 1
# add result and following points
if row["result"] == 1:
    d_table[row["home_team_id"]]["i_wins"] += 1
    d_table[row["away_team_id"]]["i_losses"] += 1
    d_table[row["home_team_id"]]["i_points"] += 3
elif row["result"] == 2:
    d_table[row["home_team_id"]]["i_draws"] += 1
    d_table[row["home_team_id"]]["i_draws"] += 1
    d_table[row["home_team_id"]]["i_points"] += 1
    d_table[row["away_team_id"]]["i_points"] += 1
elif row["result"] == 3:
    d_table[row["away_team_id"]]["i_wins"] += 1
    d_table[row["home_team_id"]]["i_losses"] += 1
    d_table[row["away_team_id"]]["i_points"] += 3
# add the goals
d_table[row["home_team_id"]]["i_goals_scored"] += row["goals_home_team"]
d_table[row["home_team_id"]]["i_goals_conceded"] += row["goals_away_team"]
d_table[row["away_team_id"]]["i_goals_scored"] += row["goals_away_team"]
d_table[row["away_team_id"]]["i_goals_conceded"] += row["goals_home_team"]

for d_club in d_table:
   d_table[d_club]["i_goals_difference"] = d_table[d_club]["i_goals_scored"] - d_table[d_club]["i_goals_conceded"]
```

Sort

```
def sorter(item):
return (item[1]["i_points"], item[1]["i_goals_difference"], item[1]["i_goals_scored"], -item[1]["i_games_played"])

d_table_sorted = dict(sorted(d_table.items(), key=sorter, reverse = True))
```

However, the result is basically that the 3 teams with equal points are ranked based on the order of the unsorted dictionary.

```
for key in d_table_sorted:
    print(key)
Real
Paris
Club Brugge
Galatasaray
```

In this example the head-to-head results are in favour of Club Brugge who  got 2 wins from 3 games agains Paris / Real. Whereas Paris has 2 wins from 4 games (and one game to go against Galatasaray) and Real has only 3 points from Paris / Club Brugge and 6 from Galatasaray.

I'm a bit stuck with to think of this conceptually. How to do this type of complex sort? I'm thinking I should a second sort of the table between the even teams after the first sort. So in this case make a table of Real, Paris and Club Brugge. But how to do this? Or is there another way around this? Any pointers would be appreciated!

Still thinking about. I could add to the latter table the results against teams with equal values for the columns on which I sort and then add those columns to the regular other ones when sorting (and hide them afterwards).

Comment: If you can use `pandas`, why not try `dataframe.sort_values(by=['col_name'])` ?

Comment: Where do you store the head to head results ? You need to access them, show us if you can. Then you can write the proper sorting function if needed, or maybe rewrite the object comparison operators ...